# How do I close my Orangedox account?

Tags: orangedox

How do I close or delete my Orangedox account? I don't seem to see that option in my account settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove Orangedox as an application from your Dropbox.  Here's an article that gives you step by step instructions on how to do that.

[How to Remove a Dropbox App](https://hub.orangedox.com/home/remove-app.docx)

Note that any links that you've created to folders or PDF's using the Business or Pro products will cease to function.  While any links you've created as a Basic user will continue to work.

If you like you can remove the links within Orangedox first.